# Starting with Phantomjs driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

Can anyone suggest me good documentations or steps to start or configure phantomJs driver in java so that i can run my test cases in remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run the selenium server in grid mode then connect the phantomjs to it after it is up as it doesn't try to reconnect if it disconnects or isn't fully up

```
./phantomjs --webdriver=5558 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444
```

which will have it listen on port 5558 (for example) but you connect through selenium an it appears as browser phantomjs on Any platform

Steps

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub 

./phantomjs --webdriver=5558 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444
```

You can then run tests as per the selenium web site https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

I use perl to run tests [http://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium%3a%3aRemote%3a%3aDriver) but there are many choices

Comment: Thanks ! But am new to this concept of Phantomjs so can you be more specific. I just downloaded the zip from http://phantomjs.org/download.html. Now how to get started ? if any documentations are there kindly send me the link.

Comment: updated with steps but just run phantomjs after you have started selenium

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add the relevant dependency of phantomJsDriver (GhostDriver) to the POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST_VERSION_HERE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find the full guide [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)

Then, work with it like with ordinary WebDriver as described in [Selenium manuals](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted), but, instead of initialising HtmlUnitDriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

Initialize PhantomsJsDriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJsDriver();
```