# Selenium+Firefox to Selenium+PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium, junit, phantomjs

I used Selenium IDE on Mozilla to test a website. After that, I created a java project in Eclipse and I imported my tests done with Selenium IDE. then I run it directly in Eclipse.

How can I run the tests with PhantomJS instead of Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: Please make it clearer what you are actually trying to do? What is the end result you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to run your tests in phantomjs, but first you have to install/unzip phantomjs somewhere and extend your PATH variable to it.

**First:** You can use the Ghostdriver java bindings through Maven `pom.xml` (you need to include the library in your Eclipse project) like in [here](http://itkosmopolit.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/quick-start-of-running-selenium-webdriver-against-phantomjs-in-java-on-windows/)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST_VERSION_HERE</version>
</dependency>
```

and then instantiate your WebDriver this way:

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

**Second:** Run phantomjs in WebDriver mode (in separate console window or as a shortcut) through

```
phantomjs --webdriver=4444
```

like in [here](http://www.andykelk.net/tech/headless-browser-testing-with-phantomjs-selenium-webdriver-c-nunit-and-mono) and then instantiate the WebDriver in java through:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
    new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
    DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs()
);
```

See also another question for use as a [hub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17808174/1816580).